# Unknown integral data type

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-mapping, hibernate-annotations

I have a database with the following specification for the ID:

> code: VARCHAR(3) - this is the primary key, a String with a maximum
>   length of 3 characters

And I am mapping the Id in the following way:

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private String code;
```

And I am getting this error when trying to invoke `session.save()`:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: Unknown integral data
>   type for ids : java.lang.String

What am I missing?

Thank you! :)

Comment: That means that the GeneratedValue should be an Integer not a java.lang.String

Comment: what is meant to generate the id? some java code before save? doubt that the database..

Comment: The database specifications says: " VARCHAR(3) - this is the primary key, a String with a maximum length of 3 characters", so it is a String...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using plain `@GeneratedValue` wont do the trick as it comes with the GenerationType.AUTO option which tells the persistence provider to decide for itself the strategy, but in case of String it cannot resolve any solution out of the box.

Normally you would go for the `uuid` custom generation strategy, but that would result in strings of length=32 which is more that your column can handle.

If you really want to avoid setting the id manually each time before save you could take advantage of the `PrePersist` entity listener:

```
@PrePersist
private void generateCodeIdentifier(){
    setCode(/* Generate the unique code identifier */);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I just read the Hibernate does not support String except uuid, which has the problem that you just pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

```
@GeneratedValue
```

cannot be used with String type, because It will return Integer type. So, if you want to use String as ID, you have to assign it manually. But it is fine to use String as ID if it suits your need.